# Create random points on a circle

Tags: r, plot, random

what is the easiest way to create random points on a circle of specific radius with noise in R? is there a library that does this kind of things?

[image]

Comment: How should the points be distributed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be more natural to sample:

- the polar angle `theta` from a uniform distribution supported on `[0, 2*pi)`,
- the polar radius `r` from a lognormal distribution supported on `(0, Inf)`, so that `log(r)` is normally distributed with mean `meanlog` and standard deviation `sdlog`.

So you could try something like this:

```r
set.seed(1L)
n <- 100L
theta <- runif(n, 0, 2 * pi)
r <- rlnorm(n, meanlog = log(2), sdlog = 0.1)
plot(r * cos(theta), r * sin(theta), asp = 1)
```

[image]

And you could generalize to multiple circles like so:

```r
circles <- function(n, mu, sigma) {
    lr <- Map(rlnorm, n = n, meanlog = mu, sdlog = sigma)
    N <- length(lr)
    n <- lengths(lr, FALSE)
    data.frame(group = rep.int(gl(N, 1L), n),
               r = unlist(lr, FALSE, FALSE),
               theta = runif(sum(n), 0, 2 * pi))
}

set.seed(1L)
d <- circles(n = c(25L, 100L, 400L), mu = log(c(1, 2, 4)), sigma = c(0, 0.05, 0.1))
str(d)
## 'data.frame':    525 obs. of  3 variables:
##  $ group: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ r    : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ theta: num  3.335 4.303 2.408 6 0.744 ...

par(mfrow = c(1L, 2L))
with(d, {
    plot(r * cos(theta), r * sin(theta), asp = 1, col = group)
    plot(r * cos(theta), r * sin(theta), asp = 1, col = cut(theta, 0:3 * 2 * pi / 3))
})
```

[image]

The function `circles` is vectorized in `n`, `mu`, and `sigma`, where `n` is the number of points in a circle and `mu` and `sigma` are the mean and standard deviation of the log radius.

Answer (score 5):

```
theta = runif(100, 0,2*pi)
x = cos(theta) + rnorm(100, 0, 0.03)
y = sin(theta) + rnorm(100, 0, 0.03)
plot(x,y, pch=20)
```

[image: Noisy circle]

Comment: It seems strange to me that you're drawing the radial noise independently for the x and y components rather than a single `r = rnorm(...)`. OP didn't specify any particular distribution, but this might introduce something a little weirder than the other way (or at least be a bit harder to make a definitive statement for what the variance of the radius is).

Comment: I see this as two separate random factors - position on the circle and variation from the circle.   I don't see how to view it as one dimensional, although if you can describe it as such,  that would be interesting.

Comment: @GregorThomas I agree, though I'm guessing you mean `r = rlnorm(...)`. It is strange to introduce three sources of variation (one `runif` and two `rnorm`) in a space with two dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `1i` to construct polar coordinates (`complex` format) and then `plot` it

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
plot(rnorm(n, 1, 0.1) * exp(1i * runif(n, 0, 2 * pi)))
```

[image]